# Is it possible to force cache clearing when a java web start application is updated?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Is it possible to force cache clearing when a java web start application is updated from the command line?

Comment: which "cache" do you want to clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to clear the cache from inside the running application, or at least I was not able to find one.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd disable the caching while developing.

Windows:
- Go go ControlPanel / Java

Linux:
- $JAVA_HOME/bin/jcontrol

-> Temporary Internet Files -> Settings ->  Untick "Keep temporary files on my computer"

Click on "Delete files" to clear all cache while you at it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Javaws documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html), you can clear the cache with:

```
javaws -uninstall
```

or

```
javaws -uninstall <jnlp>
```

However, almost by definition, you don't need to clear the cache if the application is being updated. It just seems that sometimes Javaws doesn't update applications.

I've resorted to checking a URL where I store the 'latest version' of my app. When the app starts, I fetch the URL and compare with the running version. If they differ, I popup a "There's a new version available - update now?" message box.

If the user selects to update, I use (with appropriate exception handling not shown):

```
String uri = "http://www.myserver.com/path/to/myjnlp.jnlp";
String proc = "javaws";
Process javaws = new ProcessBuilder("javaws", uri).start();
System.exit(0);
```

So far that seems to be enough, but if necessary, I could preface the javaws with:

```
Process uninstall = new ProcessBuilder("javaws", "-uninstall", uri).start();
uninstall.waitFor();
```

The only downside of this is that, if you have Desktop links, the user will be prompted to add those again. But that's a small price to pay to have updating actually working...